# onsubmit function in HTML form not working properly in angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, alert

i've opened a new Angular app and deleted everything in app.component.html so i could try out writing some basic HTML, but the simple HTML form that i copied in [from W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit)  isn't working. instead of an alert popping up when you press the "submit" button, it only refreshes the page.

i've looked online for solutions including writing "return myFunction()" instead of just "myFunction()" but it doesn't make a difference. i was planning on writing my own function that would modify the innerHTML of the page when the form is submitted, but i can't even get this alert to show up with code that works elsewhere.

what am i doing wrong?

here's the code- all i've done is remove the action attribute of the form, which was there originally

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you not using Angular? https://angular.io/start/start-forms

Comment: The example from w3schools is not an angular app. It is just a simple html/js example. You can't do it that way.